# How to detect that this is a valid VALID binary STL(stereolithography) file

Tags: stl, ascii

I have an html form in which users upload either binary or ascii [stl files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_%28file_format%29). However I want to make sure only valid binary and ascii files are uploaded.Such that if a user changes the extension of say a PDF file to `.stl` (extension for 3D binary and ascii stl files), the code must detect that its an invalid stl file.

Answer (score 5):

Quoting [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_%28file_format%29):

```
An ASCII STL file begins with the line:

`solid name`

where name is an optional string (though if name is omitted there must still be a space after solid).
```

So, to confirm an ASCII STL, check for '^solid (name)?$' on the first line.

To determine if the file is binary STL, take advantage of the length field at offset 80. It specifies the number of triangles in the file.

So, to confirm a Binary STL file, check for this expression:

```
filesize == UINT32@80 * 50 + 84
```

Number 84 here is the total size of binary STL header (80 bytes) and a 4-byte number (number of triangles) following the header.

Comment: Regardless on Wikipedia, in the real world there are binary STL files that however start with “solid”.